# Requesting clarity on the di/dt rating of thyristors

Tags: gate-driving, thyristor, scr

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foKokA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a general question about thyristors. I know that the di/dt limitation of thyristors is due to high currents flowing through regions of the thyristor that have not yet fully reached a state of full on-state conduction/uniform current density. This can cause localized overheating.

However, I am wondering about this case: What if we preemptively turn-on the thyristor before any anode->cathode current flows. For example, consider that we turn-on the thyristor under zero voltage and zero load current. Then, after waiting a millisecond or so, we ramp up the current at a very high slope, such as at 20,000\$\frac{\text{A}}{\mu\text{s}}\$. In this case, will there be any such localized overheating/damage?

My gut says there shouldn't be, since other transistors can handle very high di/dt with no ill-effects. Please let me know your thoughts!

EDIT: For example, consider this circuit. First, we turn-on the SCR1 thyristor. Then we wait. Then, we turn on the MOSFET. Will this cause deleterious effects?

Comment: You cannot turn on thyristor at zero/zero, they have a minimum trip current (for gate) and turn on voltage/current. ST Micro has a series of application notes on applying Thyristors and triacs .

Comment: I am assuming that we preemptively applying a gate->cathode voltage, that forward-biases the PN junction. Then, we reduce the thyristor to the same structure as a PN diode, right? Which can handle high di/dt? I updated the question to show a circuit of what I mean.

Comment: Turn-on at low sine voltage portion does of course limit the current. But then you're stuck at (near) 100% power factor. I'd recommend those STM appnotes for basics.

Comment: What about just the figure shown, with a DC source. You can assume that there is some inductance so the di/dt isn't infinite, but very high. I'm not concerned with turn-off for this example. Would the thyristor be damaged if a gate voltage is preemptively applied before the MOSFET is turned on?

Comment: How are you delivering "simmer" current to the thyristor? The gate alone will not reproduce the charge distribution that MT current has. If it's through another transistor... what's the thyristor doing at all, just use that?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the response. The circuit diagram here is not representative of any actual topology I am working on. But it is rather just used to explain my question.

BTW, what do you mean by "simmer" current and "MT" current? COULD the gate alone produce the charge distribution? Or does that depend on the geometry of the thyristor?

Comment: "Simmer" is an analogous trick used in photoflash circuits and other plasma devices, providing a small amount of ionization (but insufficient conductivity for full breakdown, or it's externally switched) so that the device can turn on much faster. For example, xenon flash lamps take 10s of µs to fully ionize from cold, but can do it in under 5µs with an initial bias current (which, at say 10s to 100s of mA, will be dim enough not to mind, but will require a high voltage to strike).

Comment: A thyristor has the gate on one side of the device, and the charges I think are localized there until given reason to diffuse further.  I'm not sure that they would diffuse through multiple layers (charge would just build up past the first layer and then stop, I think?). If gate diffusions are not very small and very frequently distributed, I think Spehro's answer applies (turn-on only occurs under the active gate area(s), then spreads between). So, it depends on device patterning.

Comment: Which in turn drives dI/dt, and probably voltage drop and sensitivity (gain) ratings, so -- same answer as always, refer to the datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect this is *not* allowed. The "base current" in a thyristor is primarily derived from the load current. The gate only turns a small region of the die 'on', and conduction spreads regeneratively out from that region. Without load current, there is no conduction to spread.

However there are many different [constructions of thyristors](https://frank.pocnet.net/other/Philips/elcoma/Philips_ProductBook_Thyristors_1972-04.pdf) and some are undoubtedly better than others.

Comment: Not allowed vs doesn't work.. With a decent zero crossing detection you can time the turn on at dozen volts or even less, though.

Comment: 'Not allowed' as in damage may occur to the thyristor due to excessive di/dt. Outside of absolute maximum ratings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @SpehroPefhany. 

Then, does the same limitation apply for diodes? It seems that once a gate voltage is applied, and allowed to propagate through the thyristor, the thyristor is functionally equivalent to a diode?

Comment: No, diodes and BJTs are not regenerative. Darlington transistors probably would be similar to thyristors.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks again for the answer. My understanding of a thyristor is that they are essentially two stacked diodes, P-N-P-N.  With the second "P-N" forward-biased, does it not behave identical to a diode?

Also, it was my understanding that diodes are also regenerative, since they have a reverse recovery?

If it appears I am being argumentative, my apologies. I truly am just trying to fully understand.

Comment: They would not function if they were two diodes, any more than you can make a transistor from diodes. The Wikipedia [two-transistor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyristor#/media/File:Thyristor.svg) of the thyristor may be more helpful. The "base current" for the fully conducting thyristor comes primarily (or entirely) from the load current.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @SpehroPefhany. Do you think that preemptively turning on the thyristor would have any effect at all on the di/dt limit? Or none at all? Thanks again!

Comment: My guess is that it would improve it, but not significantly.

Comment: Flipping through the linked book at the moment, jogged my memory -- you might use a saturable inductor in series, which 1. passes some "simmer" current until it fully turns on, and 2. the (MT1-MT2) junction capacitance is discharged, providing immediate current flow for charges to begin to spread out.  (I believe this has also been used with IGBTs (also 4-layer devices, but MOS driven and non-regenerative) to optimize pulse capability.)  How much dI/dt this lets you gain, who knows; I've never seen a datasheet with sat. reactor specs. May have to test yourself.

Comment: @TimWilliams That is very interesting to me. Would you be able to provide me a little more information on this sort of implementation? Very interesting idea...

Comment: @CaptainFantastic That was on p19 (33) of the thyristor book.

Comment: 'Not allowed', "excessive di/dt.". Interesting. Granted I've only worked with triacs, but di/dt I had to be concerned with had more to do with triggering the triac high on the sine wave, and/or nuisance tripping when you want if off. Especially if you use 4-quad triacs that have unfortunate characteristics to offset the sensitive low-current gate. Snubbers? yes. Babysitting the optotriac gate controller? Definitely. Prevent driving the gate before the sine wave reverses polarity? Well, I must have missed that one.